# Why is my if/else statement not ever going to else?

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm trying to write a program that takes in an argument(file name) from the command line. If it's not one of the four files that I expect then I want to print out that the correct file isn't found then exit safely. Right now when I run my code no matter what the argument is it will always run the `printf("\n\n %s \n\n", argv[1]);` line. Why is this happening?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argv[1] == "orlando.csv" || "orlando5.csv" || "florida.csv" || 
"twolines.csv"){
        printf("\n\n %s \n\n", argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("etl ERROR: File %s not found", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should read a good book on C.

Comment: Nor can you chain the `||`s like that.

Comment: As @xing said, but that doesn't actually answer the question.  The reason that the `else` block is not entered is that a string literal always evaluates true when it appears as the operand of a logical operator such as `||`.

Comment: How come I got down voted? :/

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted you, but people around here tend to be very grouchy about answering questions that they think are "too obvious."  I don't actually agree with that attitude.  Yes, if you had read and fully understood a C textbook you wouldn't have needed to ask this question, but reading and fully understanding programming textbooks is a skill you have to develop, and asking questions like this is part of the process of developing that skill, and maybe you haven't got anyone else you could ask.  So I try to be generous, but a lot of people around here won't be. :-/

Comment: My programmer soul has just died seeing that piece of code. Man you should study C before asking such questions… and yeah, people in this site may be really cruel for such questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(argv[1] == "orlando.csv" || "orlando5.csv" || "florida.csv" || "twolines.csv")
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.

First it tests whether the *address* of the string `argv[1]` is equal to the *address* of the string `"orlando.csv"`.  Since one is a command-line parameter and the other is a string literal, this test will always be false.

(Two strings with the same address must also have the same contents, but two strings with different addresses might still have the same contents.)

Then it tests whether the *address* of the string `"orlando5.csv"` is not "null".  String literals never have "null" addresses, so this test will always be *true*.

Once one entry in a chain of `||` tests has been found to be true, all further tests are skipped (this is called "short-circuit evaluation").

So the if-expression is always found to be true, and the if-branch is always executed, and the else-branch is never executed.

The if-expression you should have written is

```
if (!strcmp(argv[1], "orlando.csv") ||
    !strcmp(argv[1], "orlando5.csv") ||
    !strcmp(argv[1], "florida.csv") ||
    !strcmp(argv[1], "twolines.csv"))
```

Yes, you have to repeat the "`!strcmp(argv[1],`" part every single time.  Yes, you have to call a library function to compare strings in C.  (You will need to add `#include <string.h>` to the top of your source file.)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if(argv[1] == "orlando.csv" || "orlando5.csv" || "florida.csv" || "twolines.csv")
```

To:

```
if(  (strcmp(argv[1],"orlando.csv")==0) || 
     (strcmp(argv[1],"orlando5.csv")==0) || 
     (strcmp(argv[1],"florida.csv")==0) || 
     (strcmp(argv[1],"twolines.csv")==0) )
```

Comment: Bad style: Unnecessary parentheses around the equality comparisons, and spacing on the inside of parentheses.

Comment: @zwol - To my eyes it is more readable.  Regardless of your motivation (I have no idea what it might be) I do value your opinion, I just do not agree with it.  Your answer by the way, style notwithstanding, is very good.

Comment: Parentheses added for readability, or to avoid possible confusion, are not bad style.